# Wagtail: Creating a custom API endpoint

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I've created a Snippet called "Spotlights," and I'm wondering how I can create a custom endpoint for Snippet data with the Wagtail API. My best guess would be:

```
api_router.register_endpoint('Spotlights', BaseAPIEndpoint)
```

Is the first arg there establishing the name of the endpoint, or referencing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've figured it out: just subclass Wagtail's BaseAPIEndpoint. For example:

*endpoints.py*

```
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import BaseAPIEndpoint

class SpotlightsAPIEndpoint(BaseAPIEndpoint):
    ...
    model = Spotlight
```

*api.py*

```
from .endpoints import SpotlightsAPIEndpoint

api_router.register_endpoint('spotlights', SpotlightsAPIEndpoint)
```

Plus there are tons of ways to customize it. Just take a look at the endpoints.py file in the Wagtail repo: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/api/v2/endpoints.py

Comment: do you know how to show fields in the output as it only shows id, type and detail_url. Can we show all the fields of the model?

Comment: @Bikashkharel you can elect fields to show by specifying them like this, after `model = Spotlight` add `body_fields = BaseAPIEndpoint.body_fields + ['title', 'description'] # etc` and on a new line `listing_default_fields = BaseAPIEndpoint.listing_default_fields + ['title', 'description']`

Comment: Today you can just add api_fields = [ ... ] to the model and the BaseAPIViewSet will take care of adding these fields to the response.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wagtail documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html#configure-endpoints), the first parameter is the name of the endpoint (eg. pages, images) and this is used in the URL of the endpoint.
The second parameter is the endpoint class that handles the requests.

For example:

```
api_router.register_endpoint('pages', PagesAPIEndpoint)
api_router.register_endpoint('images', ImagesAPIEndpoint)
api_router.register_endpoint('documents', DocumentsAPIEndpoint)
```

So, I advise you to make like:

```
api_router.register_endpoint('spotlights', BaseAPIEndpoint)
```

Comment: Ah, ok. How can I point that endpoint at a model (like how PagesAPIEndpoint is pointed at the Page model)?

Comment: Again, according to documentation: "It’s likely that you would need to export some custom fields over the API. This can be done by adding a list of fields to be exported into the api_fields attribute for each page model." or you can use a custom serializer: "Serialisers are used to convert the database representation of a model into JSON format. You can override the serializer for any field using the serializer keyword argument." - http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html#adding-custom-page-fields

Comment: I saw that in the documentation, but I don't think that's what I am looking for, because it's talking about custom fields in models extending the Page model. My question is, is there a way to create a custom endpoint for a model that is a Snippet, not Page. I'll keep tinkering with it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Latest Wagtail version - 2.15 +

in your views file, import your model and BaseApiViewSet

```
from .models import CustomModel
from wagtail.api.v2.views import BaseAPIViewSet

class BusinessLocationViewSet(BaseAPIViewSet):

    model = BusinessLocation
    body_fields = BaseAPIViewSet.body_fields + ['id', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', etc, etc...]
```

and in the api.py file in the project folder, import your model and expose it to the api as follows:

```
from custommodel.views import MyModel

api_router.register_endpoint('custom', MyModel)
```

and now your model will be accessible from the `api/v2/custom` endpoint

Answer (score 1):

I needed to modify glls's solution a bit to make it work. To expose the endpoint in `api.py`:

```
from .views import CustomViewSet

api_router.register_endpoint("custom", CustomViewSet)
```

It's also common to add filtering functionality. In `views.py`:

```
from wagtail.images.api.v2.views import BaseAPIViewSet, FieldsFilter

from .models import Custom

class CustomViewSet(BaseAPIViewSet):
    model = Custom
    body_fields = BaseAPIViewSet.body_fields + [
        "name"
    ]
    filter_backends = [
        FieldsFilter
    ]
```

You can now filter the `Custom` snippet like normal: `/api/v2/custom/?name=something`

Comment: nice! +1 - thanks for posting + details